# How to check if an url has numbers with fileEntityId or not?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9

I have some urls as below:

```
https://example.com/file/filegetrevision.do?fileEntityId=738007
9&cs=4Pzbb2jPu3EHBzv8RQHrGcPm4hZZkRC-CfH0my4dP0M.arv


https://example.com/file/filegetrevision.do?fileEntityId=&cs=2L
5cx4UsMsFJgM05pPtB_Z8dRdL4CXLLcTeDhGPDBIg.arv


https://example.com/file/filegetrevision.do?fileEntityId=2555874&cs=2L
5cx4UsMsFJgM05pPtB_Z8dRdL4CXLLcTeDhGPDBIg.arv
```

Now I need to check which url has `numbers` with `fileEntityId` or which has not? Any help in this regard? say first and third URL has `738007` and `2555874` numbers with `fileEntityId` but the second doesn't.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As much as I love regexes, there are more appropriate tools included in the standard library:

```
require 'uri'
require 'cgi'

url = "https://example.com/file/filegetrevision.do?fileEntityId=7380079&cs=4Pzbb2jPu3EHBzv8RQHrGcPm4hZZkRC-CfH0my4dP0M.arv"
query = URI::parse(url).query # => "fileEntityId=7380079&cs=4Pzbb2jPu3EHBzv8RQHrGcPm4hZZkRC-CfH0my4dP0M.arv"
fileEntityId = CGI::parse(query)['fileEntityId'] # => ["7380079"]
```

Then you can check if it is a number or not.

Comment: `+1` to you! I was not introduced to this libaray. I have tried the one @sergio showwn!

Comment: Ah. `CGI::parse`! Indeed, this is better :)

Answer (score 1):

Here we use regexes to find out if a string contains "fileEntityId=" followed by one or more digits:

```
urls = ['https://example.com/file/filegetrevision.do?fileEntityId=7380079&cs=4Pzbb2jPu3EHBzv8RQHrGcPm4hZZkRC-CfH0my4dP0M.arv',
  'https://example.com/file/filegetrevision.do?fileEntityId=&cs=2L5cx4UsMsFJgM05pPtB_Z8dRdL4CXLLcTeDhGPDBIg.arv',
  'https://example.com/file/filegetrevision.do?fileEntityId=2555874&cs=2L5cx4UsMsFJgM05pPtB_Z8dRdL4CXLLcTeDhGPDBIg.arv']


urls.map {|u| !!(u =~ /fileEntityId=\d+/)} # => [true, false, true]
```

Comment: `+1` to you to correct my one, I forgot to put `+` in my one. Thus my one didn't workrd!